# jQuery.trigger('click') results in "change" Event in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, event-handling

```
$('#myRadioButton').change(function(event) {
    var eventType = event.type;
    $(this).trigger('click'); // In IE8 only, this results in endless loop
});
```

The code snippet above results in a change event being fired in IE8 and hence an endless loop is started when my radio button is selected. This is not the expected behaviour, as a 'click' event certainly is not a 'change' event. In other browsers and IE9+ the code works as expected (i.e., not an endless loop).

The variable `eventType` equals `"change"` in IE8, both for initial, user triggered 'change' event, but also for the subsequent calls to itself.

What is the reason for this behavior and how to stop IE8 from being a jerk and act like a normal browser?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason - no idea sorry.

'Work Around' :-

```
function radioChange() {
    $(this).off('change', radioChange);
    $(this).trigger('click');
    $(this).on('change', radioChange);
}

$('#myRadioButton').change(radioChange);
```

`trigger` is synchronous, so removing the `change`, then triggering the `click`, then re-attach the `change` should work.

Comment: BG101, thanks for your comment and workaround. Actually, I was thinking of a similar workaround by using an attribute which is set when change event is fired, retaining the radio button's previous value and then just returning false if no change between current and previous value.